# How to stop the method continuously looping

Tags: java

I am currently trying to complete a program with multiple classes in java that will allow the user to input information to help him or her book tickets, accommodation, parking, etc for a rock festival. I have started with one of the classes 'accommodation' to return the correct input of the user to the main class, however, I have found when I run the program and enter option 3, it immediately loops continuously which I have to terminate. I have searched online for a way to stop the loop, and for it to return the correct inputted information to no avail, I would appreciate any help to a very new new noob, before this loop turns me loopy!
Below is my main class and the class 'accommodation'. thank you in advance and apologies for any messy coding I have, as I have been trying various options as I have said before.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class clydeRockfest {

public static void main(String[] args) {




    boolean quit = false;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice;    // Display the menu
    int answer = 0;

    Accommodation accommodation = new Accommodation();
    //accommodation.getaccommodation();


    do{

    System.out.println("1\t Festgoers");
    System.out.println("2\t Ticket");
    System.out.println("3\t Accommodation");
    System.out.println("4\t Transport");
    System.out.println("5\t Parking");
    System.out.println("0\t Quit");


    System.out.println("Please enter your choice:");

    //Get user's choice
    choice=in.nextInt();
     if(choice == 0)
         quit=true;


    //Display the title of the chosen module
    switch (choice) {

   break;

        case 3: accommodation.getaccommodation();
            System.out.println("You require " + answer + " accommodation."); 
   break;


        case 0: 
            quit=true;
   break;

        default: System.out.println("Invalid choice, please choose again.");

    } //end of switch
} //end of the main method
    while(!quit);
} //end of class

}
```

```
public class Accommodation {

     private String accommodation;

     void getaccommodation(){


        int no = 0;   // no accommodation at all required
        int self_Pitch = 0;  // chosen if requiring a pitch
        int tent = 0;  // chosen if using a tent
        int answer = 0;
        int choice = 0;

        boolean done = false;


        System.out.println("Do you require accommodation?");
        System.out.println();

        // Answer validation loop
        boolean validanswer = true;
        while (!validanswer){   

        System.out.println("Enter:(1=NO, 2=SELF-PITCH, 3=TENT)");
        System.out.println();


        if(answer > 0 && answer < 4){
            validanswer = true;
            done = true;
        }// ends if
        else{
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("That is not a valid answer, please choose again:");
        System.out.println();

        }   // ends else
    } //ends while
}

        public void setaccommodation(String accommodation){
        this.accommodation = accommodation;
       }
```

Output:

```
Please enter your choice:
3
Do you require accommodation?

You require 0 accommodation.
1    Festgoers
2    Ticket
3    Accommodation
4    Transport
5    Parking
0    Quit
Please enter your choice:
```

Comment: Hey! Welcome to SO. Please include only the code relevant to your question. Not your entire class. Thank you!

Comment: as Muhammad suggested it would probably be best to just post the code that is looping indefinately.

Comment: Thank you for posting all your code.  This is a reasonable amount of code to post.  Too often people attempt to post the "code relevant to the question", but because they are dealing with something they don't understand in the first place, they miss code they didn't realize was relevant.  I think it best to post all code; if there's too much, we suggest recreating the problem with a reasonable amount of code and posting all of that.

Comment: thank you and apologies Muhammad and thermite

Comment: @arcy: This is not a reasonable amount of code. The looping occurs in just one of the two classes, so a main program with a simple call to that method would have sufficed. Also, there is a lot of commented out code , which definitely should be removed.

Comment: @arcy as Keppil said, this is not reasonable, there is a lot of extra code that isn't relevant to that loop that should have been removed.

Comment: Alex_E: no need to apologize, you are new here so its understandable. If you could edit your code to slim things down it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. I'm not sure about the value you are reading, so please, print user input to check it is read properly. Add this below "nextInt()": System.out.println("choice:[" + choice + "]");

Comment: whereabouts would I input this code Juanjo, I presume without the apostrophes too, thanks

Comment: @Keppil I agree that the comments of code tried and not being used should be commented out.  I do not agree that an OP should decide "what is relevant" and post only that.  People asking questions -- especially fundamental questions -- cannot tell what is relevant, and are better off posting code that runs and illustrates their problem, not just "relevant portions".  If they don't understand loops all that well, perhaps they don't understand scope, or pass-by-value, or whatever, and one of those could cause such a problem.

Comment: @arcy: That is the beauty of asking them to trim down the code first. They might remove code they deem irrelevant that isn't, notice that the problem is gone, and solve the problem themselves. Also, it forces OP to think through the code before posting. Trimming down the code helps OP at least as much as it helps us.

Answer (score 1):

you prime your loop by setting `done=false` but never set `done = true` so your loop will never end

Answer (score 0):

You have two loops checking if user is done, and the condition of the first one (with the `done`) variable is never changed. Just remove this loop, and you should be fine.

Also, it looks like the condition for the second loop variable should be

```
if (answer > 0 && answer < 4)
```

to match your menu alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You never set `done` to `true`. It seems you may need to do it here:

```
if(answer >=0 && answer <=4){
    validanswer = true;
    done = true;
}
else{
    //code
}
```

However, I'm not even sure you need that outer loop in the first place:

```
while(!done){
```

It seems redundant.

Comment: thank you for your help, as previously stated I have set done to true and I also removed the outer loop, this seems to stop the looping however it stops it altogether with stating that no accommodation is required without the user being asked the multiple choice, however I will continue to persevere with this, thank you to everyone for all their help once again, great site too, cheers

Comment: @Alex_E You should only need to do one. Either set `done` to `true` or remove the outer loop. You should post your updated coded in the original post, so we can further help you

Comment: Here is the class updated as above and also the output it gives, as you can see it still clears the statement with " 0 accommodation required", before a choice is able to be input, this is why I presumed I required the outer loop too.